# PyAPNS not delivering push messages to iOS devices in production environment

Tags: python, iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

since yesterday (2013-04-23) we have experienced problems to delivery notifications via APNS' production gateway, despite development works fine.

I haven't made changes in the code that sends the message, so, it's odd to see it just stopped to work.

This is the payload:

```
{"driver_pk":"505978566e77c33341000610","booking":{"pk":"5164d705b6c1213479c2fe5b"},"aps":{"sound":"booking_new_offer","alert":{"loc-key":"MSG_NB"}},"creation":"2013-04-24T07:44:28+00:00","type":"new-booking","param":{}}
```

As you guys can see, the size is 220 (less than 256) and this is a simple ASCII string, with no special chars at all.

Using pyapns library to do the sending job: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns in most recent version 1.1.2 (also tried previous like 1.1.1 etc)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If it already worked in production,  you should check whether your production push certificate has expired,  and create a new one if it has.

If it never worked in production you should make sure you're using a production certificate and production device tokens when pushing to production apns server.

EDIT :

Did the production notifications stop working after you tested development notifications? If that's the case, the problem may be that your database contains both sandbox and production device tokens, and sending a sandbox device token to the production APNS server will drop the connection, which can also cause good messages that were sent after the bad one to be dropped.

Comment: hummm... yes, it worked before, for a long time. The certificates (both dev and prod) expire in October 2013, so, it shouldn't be the certificate.